# How to change a string to hex

Tags: python

So I have this normal string and I want to get its hex value in Python.
Example:
":" I want the program to output "0x3a" 
However I searched didn't find anything here. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: please show your attempt...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What is the "normal string"? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: I tried what that guy Rafal gave me ..That's all I found on this site..But it's not what I mean

Comment: You question is too vague to be answerable. What do you  mean ??

Comment: Joachim I mean like "lol" I want its hex value 0x...

Comment: You mean you want the ASCII values of the characters in the string? Otherwise you make no sense, as "lol" can't be converted to a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Man it's all fixed now..Thanks anyways :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python2 has this easy way

```
>>> "Hello".encode("hex")
'48656c6c6f'
```

Python3 is not so bad

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'Hello')
b'48656c6c6f'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked :D.I googled and didn't find it..Stange.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want

```
In [152]: x = "12"

In [153]: hex(int(x))
Out[153]: '0xc'
```

Comment: Yes but it's solved now..Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 0):

With simple cast.

```
> int('0xFF', 16)
< 255
```

Comment: Man I saw this much..It's not what I mean...I mean like 
"string" how to change it to hex value like 0x...